# Proof using the uniqueness of prime factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Today I saw a statement that for a,b and n are positives integers, a divides b if and only a^n divides b^n. I know if a divides b then a^n must divide b^n. But why if a^n divide b^n, then a must divide b? My friend told me it can be proved by the uniqueness of prime factorization, but I can't understand. Can anyone show me a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}p_3^{r_3}\dots$ and $b=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}p_3^{s_3}\dots$ where $p_1,p_2,..$ are the primes occuring in $a$ or $b$, and $r_i,s_i\ge 0$.

Then $a|b$ means that $r_i\le s_i$ for all $i$. On the other hand, $a^n=p_1^{nr_1}p_2^{nr_2}\dots$, $\ b^n=p_1^{ns_1}p_2^{ns_2}\dots$, so 
$a^n\,|\,b^n$ means that $nr_i\le ns_i$ for all $i$.

But if $n>0$, these statements are equivalent.

Comment: Two questions, first, "a^n|b^n means that nri≤nsi" why is this true? second, why does this imply that a divides b? I am not quite understanding this, could you explain more? Thank you very much.

Comment: If n<m, then a^m / a^n = a^(m-n), with m-n positive. So if for each prime, nri<nsi, then p^(nsi-nri) has positive exponent.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this now. But to reach this conclusion, we must first prove that "nri≤nsi for all i", why is this true? Also, why is n>0 necessary?

Comment: I have written the prime decomposition of $a^n$ and $b^n$. A number $A$ divides $B$ iff for each prime $p$, the exponent of $p$ in $A$ is less or equal than that in $B$. The exponent of $p_i$ in $a^n$ is $nr_i$ and that in $b^n$ is $ns_i$.